# getting post data from request is coming back null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post

I am using Asp.net MVC and I'm trying to debug my method by writing the post data to a log file.

I took this post [C# .net equivilent of HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708110/c-sharp-net-equivilent-of-http-raw-post-data) and tried to run with it.

Here is my `ActionResult`:

```
   public ActionResult Receipt(string id)
    {
      try
      {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\LOGS\RECEIPTLOG.TXT", true))
        {
          sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
          sw.WriteLine("Start Receipt: " + DateTime.Now);
          sw.WriteLine("Browser: " + Request.Browser.Id);
          sw.WriteLine("Browser Version: {0}.{1}", Request.Browser.MajorVersion, Request.Browser.MinorVersion);
          sw.WriteLine("Request.UserHostAddress: " + Request.UserHostAddress);
          if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
          {
            sw.WriteLine("Request.UrlReferrer: " + Request.UrlReferrer);
          }

          foreach (var headerKey in Request.Headers.Keys)
          {
            var headerValues = Response.Headers.GetValues(headerKey.ToString());
            if (headerValues != null)
            {
              sw.WriteLine("Response Header: {0}, Value: {1}", headerKey, String.Join(";", headerValues));
            }
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("error:" + ex.Message);
      }

      var control = Logging.StartLog();
      control.Source = SourceEnum.WebPortal;

      try
      {
        Logging.WriteLog("Start Receipt");

        var count = 0;
        var postVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {
          Logging.WriteLog("count: " + count);
          Logging.WriteLog(string.Format("key:   {0}    Value:   {1}", key, Request.Form[key]));
          postVals.Add(key, Request.Form[key]);
          Logging.WriteLog("finished count: " + count);
          count++;
        }
        Logging.WriteLog("finished processing ALLKeys");
        var paymentReq = createPaymentRequest(postVals);
        Logging.WriteLog("finished processing 'var paymentReq = createPaymentRequest(postVals)' ");

        Logging.WriteLog("_client.RecordPaymentWithRequest start");
        var receipt = _client.RecordPaymentWithRequest(paymentReq);
        Logging.WriteLog("Running _client.RecordPaymentWithRequest complete");
        var retval = PartialView(receipt.Duplicate ? "Duplicate Receipt" : "Receipt", receipt);
        Logging.WriteLog(string.Format("retval: {0}", retval));
        return retval;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Logging.WriteException(ex);
        throw;
      }
      finally
      {
        Logging.WriteLog(control, "End RegisterNewAccountEmail");

        try
        {
          using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\LOGS\RECEIPTLOG.TXT", true))
          {
            sw.WriteLine("Stop Receipt: " + DateTime.Now);
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("error:" + ex.Message);
        }

      }
    }
```

This is what ends up in my log:

```
-------------------------------------------
Start Receipt: 1/14/2014 7:17:07 AM
Browser: internetexplorer
Browser Version: 11.0
Request.UserHostAddress: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Request.UrlReferrer: website url here
Stop Receipt: 1/14/2014 7:17:07 AM
```

As you can see there is no header information being written.

Am I going about this wrong to dump the post data into a log file? If not, any ideas why my header information isn't writing to the log?

** UPDATE **

I added this to my logging within the first try/catch:

```
sw.WriteLine("Request.Headers.Keys.Count: " + Request.Headers.Keys.Count);
```

and this is the results:

```
Request.Headers.Keys.Count: 11
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are POSTing? GET requests have no body. What's `Request.ContentLength`?

Comment: Debug you code - are there any values in headerValues? Also, make sure you POST your data: add the POST-attribute to your action.

Comment: I added additional information, keys.count is 11. I assume that means there is post data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Request.Headers.AllKeys instead of Keys.

[AllKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.allkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an array of strings which is what you want.
[Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a [NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: `foreach (var headerKey in Request.Headers.AllKeys)` Is this correct? If so, it still gives me no output.

Comment: [It should work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628584/how-to-dump-asp-net-request-headers-to-string), also the documentation page for the header properties has an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers.aspx) where they do exactly what you want.

Comment: I changed the loop to use the example that you gave and it worked! Thanks!